# Java Script Regular Expression for 1234.1234,123.12,0100.111,XXXX.XXXX

Tags: javascript, regex

I have a requirement to capture the ',' separated values which are the following pattern XXXX.XXXX,XXX.XXX the max digits are 4 on both side of the '.'

thanks

Comment: What's your question? Where's the effort? What have you tried so far?

Comment: It seems you are looking for [`String.prototype.split`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/split) method.

Comment: I think you need `if (s.test(/^\d{1,4}\.\d{1,4}(?:,\d{1,4}\.\d{1,4})*$/)) { alert("Correct!"); }`, see [demo](https://regex101.com/r/mIQf7U/1).

Answer (score 0):

Here's a better one:

```
(?:^|,)(\d{1,4}\.\d{1,4})(?=,|$)
```

Pushpesh Kumar Rajwanshi's solution has some issues. For the following pattern

```
13456.1234,433.544
```

It would output this:

```
3456.1234
```